# Crystal parser creates an ASTNode that should be Crystal::Expressions at runtime but is somehow a Crystal::Nop

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, crystal-lang

```
require "compiler/crystal/syntax"

s = "a = 5; puts a + 3"

nodes = Crystal::Parser.parse(s)
puts nodes.class                      # => Crystal::Expressions
puts nodes.is_a? Crystal::Expressions # => true
puts nodes.is_a? Crystal::Nop         # => false

puts nodes.expressions
```

So, I would assume the last expression to give an Array (or an ArrayLiteral node). However, I get

```
undefined method 'expressions' for Crystal::Nop (compile-time type is Crystal::ASTNode+)
```

Which makes no sense. `.class` and `.is_a?` are runtime checks, so the `nodes` , which has a compile-time type of `ASTNode` should be `Crystal::Expressions`, not `Crystal::Nop`.

The behaviour is the same on crystal versions 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.26.0, 0.26.1 and the version currently on the master branch of the git repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is raised at compile time because not *all* subclasses of `Crystal::ASTNode` have `#expressions` method. `Crystal::Nop` just happens to be the first such subclass the compiler checks and subsequently decides to throw an error. The way to fix the code is:

```
require "compiler/crystal/syntax"

s = "a = 5; puts a + 3"

nodes = Crystal::Parser.parse(s)
case nodes
when Crystal::Expressions
    puts nodes.expressions
when Crystal::Nop
    puts "It's a nop"
else
    puts "Unhandles case for #{nodes.class}"
end
```

Alternatively, you can force the compiler to assume it's `Crystal::Expressions` by using `.as`:

```
nodes.as(Crystal::Expressions).expressions
```

Credit for this answer goes to [straight-shoota](https://github.com/straight-shoota) on this [Github issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/7013)